# Why we cant update UI from worker thread? same as other variables/object

Tags: c#, multithreading

Feel like asking a stupid question but I want to know answer. I don’t need any code to update UI from worker thread I know how to update UI from worker/thread pool.

I want to know that why we get this error “Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.” whenever any worker thread try to update UI controls? and Why not this error come when worker thread access object created by Main thread and there is no UI interaction?

See below example

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    TextBox textbox2 = null;
    List<int> collection = new List<int>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textbox2 = new TextBox();
    }
    public void UpdateTextBox()
    {
        collection.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        textbox2.Text = "hi, ThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
        panel1.Controls.Add(textbox2);//If remove this line... will work with worker thread.
    }
    private void btnMainThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTextBox();
    }
    private void btnWorkerThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(UpdateTextBox);
        t1.Start();//Will get error. why?
    }
}
```

How we can apply same kind of restruction for my "collection" variable.?

Comment: As you probably may know you can use `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` to let cross thread calls. I personally never have any problems when using this on task like updating text box. Actually I am curies if anyone have app killer error with cross thread call?

Comment: @Logman yes I have. Early versions of the .net framework did not include the cross-thread check so it was very easy to make this kind of mistake. Like you have experienced, most of the time there were no problems, but every once in a while, your user interface will die. Your form's user interface will be replaced by a white background and nothing will repaint anymore. You will be forced to kill the application.

Comment: @BlueStrat could you elaborate more about this error in your answer? Did you found out what caused it or on what circumstances it appears? I never have such experience mostly there was a graphic glitch or occasionally exception.

Comment: @Logman, in our case, we had a ListView (grid mode) component that was updated several times a second from a secondary thread. The application would block as I described, sometimes it would take hours,  other times it would take days. We were baffled until we found in the Win32 API docs that all functions should be called from the thread that created the controls.  This was back in .Net 1.1 days, so there was no Invoke() yet.  We solved the problem by using a  queue. The updates were enqueued by the secondary thread, and a Timer (running in the UI thread) drained the queue and updated the UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer -I think - you are looking for (why and how the exception is raised) is because **there is explicit code inside the `Control` class's `Handle` property that will check if the code that wants to access the property is running on the same thread that created the Control (the User-interface thread).**

You can check the reference source for the `Handle` property [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,f8a3ff8836ea5045).  The actual thread check occurs inside the implementation of the `InvokeRequired` property, that you can also check [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/d3ab1956c1b4c3db.html).

Early versions of the .net Framework did not include this check, so it was very easy to access the user interface from a different thread. The reason why we <s>can't</s> shouldn't do it is because there is a great portion of the Win32 API code base that is not thread-safe,  so calling it from a single thread is the only way to guarantee no concurrency problems will happen in a multi-threaded application.

The `Handle` property will be accessed before the control internally calls any related Win32 API function that interacts with it (you can think of the handle as the 'this' reference inside the WIN32 API), so it was a very good candidate for centralizing the cross-thread check.

**If I understand correctly from your comments, you want to simulate the same behavior (to raise an exception) when a worker thread tries to update a certain value (not necessarily a user interface element) 'owned' by a different thread. In this case you could adopt the same strategy that the framework is using**.

If you analyze the code for `InvokeRequired`, it is simply comparing the current thread's ID against the value returned by  `SafeNativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and returning `true` if there is a mismatch.  This causes the cross-thread exception to be raised in the `Handle` property's getter accessor.   **In your case you could store the ID of the thread that is allowed to access the variable or resource and manually raise the exception if there is a mismatch between this stored ID and the ID of the thread attempting to access the guarded value.**

Comment: Perfect answer, this is what I want to know. many thanks @BlueStrat

Comment: Thank you @PankajRawat, glad to be helpful  =)

Comment: Spot on, thanks for clearing that up - I misunderstood the question at first.

Answer (score 1):

In a windows application whenever you try to access a windows forms or controls object from a different thread then you won't be able to do. To handle such kind to scenario, you can use **Invoke** to access a cross thread object:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know that thing but I want to know why? and why get error with winform control not with variable?

Comment: It's because Windows Form controls are not inherently thread safe. Its dangerous if multiple threads access the Control at the same time and you can't use a `lock(sync)` as you can with variables.

Comment: It is an error to call this control functions on the same thread that the control belongs to. You need execute the action (delegate) on the thread that owns this Control's underlying window handle. If the control's handle doesn't exist yet, the Invoke function will follow up the control's parent chain until it finds a control or form that does have a window handle. If no appropriate handle can be found, invoke will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

As you are doing things "behind the scenes" (not in the main UI thread/locking it up), you cannot access the UI as you normally would from outside of a child thread. To access the UI and interact with the user, you must tell the main UI object that it needs to display/do something from within the thread so that the UI operations don't conflict with what the thread operations want to do. This is typically only true for actual UI objects (forms, buttons, labels, etc), most variables can be modified from the child thread without much harm (take caution to that, violate variables are always a good idea and variable locking in that scenario to avoid unintended threading errors).

Using "`this.invoke(new Action(() => { UpdateText(); }));`" is what you are looking for in your case. This can be called inline from child thread without causing a cross threading operation error, you'll just want to make sure you the form's not disposed of, disposing of, etc. You can include multiple methods within the {} of the invoke.

Your specific example

```
T1 Thread = new Thread(UpdateText);
T1.Start();

function UpdateText()
{
    this.invoke(new action(() =>{ textbox1.Text = "Some Text"; });
}
```

A Useful Example

The "Loading" form

```
public partial class WaitWindow : Form
{

    public WaitWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal void UpdateMessage(string Message)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = Message;
    }

}
```

"Dialog" class

```
public class Dialog
{
    private static WaitForm WaitBox;

    public static void UpdateMessage(string Message)
    {
        if (WaitBox != null && WaitBox.IsHandleCreated && !WaitBox.IsDisposed && !WaitBox.IsDisposing)
        {
            WaitBox.Invoke(new Action(() =>{ WaitBox.UpdateMessage(Message); });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is absolutely correct to update UI control from worker thread but I want to throw a same error ("Cross-thread operation not valid") when worker thread will try to add/update variable created by main thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this to update any control from other threads

```
public void AppendTextBox(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] {value});
            return;
        }
        textBox1.Text += value;
    }
```